# Prove that if $x_k$ is not eventually monotone increasing, then There exists positive integer $j$ such that $\sup[x_k:k\in \mathbb{N}]=x_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$x_k$ is eventually monotone increasing is equivalent to

For every $k\geq k_0$, $x_k\leq x_{k+1}$

If $x_k$ is not eventually monotone increasing,

then There exists positive integer $j$ such that $\sup[x_k:k\in \mathbb{N}]=x_j$

I found that

If There does not exist $j$ then

For all $k$, $x_k<\sup[x_k:k\in \mathbb{N}]$

What is next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion is not true in general, consider $(x_n)_n$ defined as $x_n = 1 - 1/n$ when $n$ is odd and $x_n = 0$ when $n$ is even. Then $x$ is not eventually monotone increasing, and yet $\sup_n(x_n) = 1 \neq x_n \forall n$.

A true statement might be something like, if $x$ has no monotone increasing subsequence, *then* $\exists j$ such that $x_j = \sup_n x_n$.